# Minimal C/C++ program that segfaults?

Tags: c++, c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to set up the way my server handles core dumps. In order to test it, I'd need a program that always segfaults.

Is there a simple example program that always segfaults?

Comment: Coredump or segfault? Usually `abort()` is enough to cause a core dump, and that's actually part of a *real* program. A segfault never is.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Tag says C, title says both.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour : I meant the minimal program, written *either* in C or C++, that segfaults. You can add the C++ tag if you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`main;`

Is portable, and segfault in 5chars.
It's a variable declaration - `int` type is implied (feature copied from B language) and `0` is default value. When executed this tries to execute a number (numbers aren't executable), and causes `SIGSEGV`.

Source: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-raises-a-sigsegv

Comment: Correct, but woefully lacking in any form of explanation as to why it does that (I know why, but not everyone does)

Answer (score 10):

`main() { *(int *)0xdeadbeef = 37; }` should do it.

Comment: why 37? it should be 42!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
long* ptr = 0x0; //-- you can also use other random values and likely you will segfault
printf("%f", *ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
main() {
char *p = NULL;
char c = *p;
}
```

Comment: This can be eliminated by the compiler's optimizer. You want the pointer to point to a volatile object for this to work.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze : just don't turn optimizations on :)

Answer (score 0):

this should die:

```
int main() {
    char *die;
    printf("%d",(int *)die * 200);
    return 0;
}
```

edit:

```
int main() {
    char *die;
    int killer = 200;
    while(1) {
       printf("%d",(int *)die * killer);
       killer = killer * killer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it? It's UB, so it might, but it could also just print an arbitrary number.

Comment: Ah, doesn't even compile with gcc. You'd have to explicitly convert the `char*` to an integer for it to compile (wasn't sure whether the compiler permitted an implicit conversion, the standard doesn't, but I think only a diagnostic is required, not termination of the compilation).

Comment: Now it's still UB since you're using the indeterminate value of the uninitialised pointer, but I don't know of any implementation where that would actually crash. What is the idea how you want to cause a crash?

Comment: Then you should probably dereference the pointer in some place.